Google bot doesn't loading react js normally
I have a react js website. Sometimes Google bot doesn't load the original javascripts randomly and lost the page index.
Is there a way to force google to fetch a javascript resource in react page?

I'm not an expert but maybe using Next.js for SSR or SSG.
These methods will provide fully-rendered HTML pages, making it easier for search engines to crawl and index your site.
Next.js, guide to SSR and SSG in React
